# parsing gives error in asyn-task in android

Tags: android, parsing, android-asynctask

Please following code I am not getting why it's not loading data. below activity is started after splash activity & here I am trying to download data from server & parse it & try to attach it to spinner but it force close the application saying element not found at line 1 so I am not getting why it's not working...

Edited:--- Code is working on android 2.3 & above but not on android 2.2  minimum sdk version required is 8 (Android 2.2)

```
public class Registration extends Activity{

private List<RegisterMessage> regis_msg;
private List<CountryMessage> country_msg;
ArrayList<String> countryName,countryCode,isoCode,countryFlag;
EditText fname,sname,email,mobileno;
Spinner country;
AppPreferences ap;
Button btnregister;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);

    country = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.country);
    fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
    sname  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sname);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    mobileno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileno);

    ap = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());

//  mobileno.setText(ap.getPreferences("MobileNo"));

    btnregister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnregister);

    btnregister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(fname.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Firstname.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fname.setFocusable(true);
                    fname.requestFocus();
                }else if (sname.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Surname.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sname.setFocusable(true);
                    sname.requestFocus();
                }else if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    email.setFocusable(true);
                    email.requestFocus();
                }else if (mobileno.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Mobile No.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    email.setFocusable(true);
                    email.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    new RegistrationTry().execute();
                }
            }
      });

    if(!isOnline()) {
        Log.v("isOnline",isOnline()+"");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You device is not connected to the internet.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        new CountryData().execute();
    }

}

public boolean isOnline(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isconnected;
    if (netInfo==null || !netInfo.isConnected())
    isconnected=false;
    else
    isconnected=true;
    Log.v("isOnliNe",isconnected+"");
    return isconnected;
}   

class CountryData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
   // private CustomizeDialog Dialog = new CustomizeDialog(Registration.this);
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading please wait........");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Object...params) {
        try{
            String url= newsReaderUrls.BASE_URL + newsReaderUrls.COUNTRY_URL;
            Log.v("URL",url);
            BaseFeedParser parser  =  new BaseFeedParser(url);
            country_msg = parser.CountryParse();
            countryName = new ArrayList<String>();
            countryCode = new ArrayList<String>();
            isoCode = new ArrayList<String>();
            countryFlag = new ArrayList<String>();
            countryName.add(0, "Select");
            for (CountryMessage msg : country_msg){
                 countryName.add(msg.getCountryName());
                 countryCode.add(msg.getCountryCode());
                 isoCode.add(msg.getIsoCode());
                 countryFlag.add(msg.getCountryFlag());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
        return null;
    }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if(Dialog.isShowing()){
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
        String[] array_spinner = countryName.toArray(new String[countryName.size()]);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_spinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        country.setAdapter(adapter);
        String cn = ap.getPreferences("CountryIso");
        if(!cn.equals("")){
            int index = isoCode.indexOf(cn);
            country.setSelection(index+1);
        }else if(countryName.indexOf("Nigeria") !=  -1){
            country.setSelection(countryName.indexOf("Nigeria")+1);
        }
    }
}

class RegistrationTry extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   // private CustomizeDialog Dialog = new CustomizeDialog(Registration.this);
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
    int foreward;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading please wait........");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
        try{
            String defaultC_code="ng";
            /*if(countryName.size()<0){
                defaultC_code = "ng";
            }else{
                int index = country.getSelectedItemPosition();
                defaultC_code = isoCode.get(index-1);
            }*/
            ap.savePreferences("MobileNo", mobileno.getText().toString());
            String url= newsReaderUrls.BASE_URL + newsReaderUrls.REGISTER_URL + "Mobile="+ mobileno.getText().toString()+
                        "&First_Name="+fname.getText().toString()+"&Last_Name="+sname.getText().toString()+
                        "&Email="+email.getText().toString()+"&Device_Type=Phone&Device_Platform=Android"+
                        "&ISO_Code=" + defaultC_code;
            Log.v("Login", url);
            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser(url);
            regis_msg = parser.RegisterParse();

            for (RegisterMessage msg : regis_msg){
                Log.v("Status", msg.getStatus());
                foreward = Integer.parseInt(msg.getStatus());
            }

        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(foreward == 2 || foreward == 3){
            ap.savePreferences("Registered", "yes");
            Intent i = new Intent(Registration.this,DashBoard.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration failed please try later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(Dialog.isShowing()){
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

}

LogCat

```
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at com.websoft.android.parser.BaseFeedParser.CountryParse(BaseFeedParser.java:189)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at com.websoft.android.newsreel.Registration$CountryData.doInBackground(Registration.java:117)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at com.websoft.android.newsreel.Registration$CountryData.doInBackground(Registration.java:1)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599): Caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:553)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:483)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:320)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:277)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at android.util.Xml.parse(Xml.java:87)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     at com.websoft.android.parser.BaseFeedParser.CountryParse(BaseFeedParser.java:187)
10-31 16:13:41.022: ERROR/AndroidNews(599):     ... 8 more
10-31 16:13:41.022: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(599): Shutting down VM
10-31 16:13:41.042: WARN/dalvikvm(599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.websoft.android.newsreel.Registration$CountryData.onPostExecute(Registration.java:140)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-31 16:13:41.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Code seems fine, can't say anything about error but its better you post the logcat output.

Comment: it's a ParseException are you sure that the file returned by the server (xml right ?) is well formed ?

Comment: yes it's proper all other urls are working but this link gives error I don't get anything I rechecked code again & again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you were doing `country_msg = parser.CountryParse();` There was a parsing exception `ExpatParser$ParseException` .

> At line 1, column 0: no element found

This means the file is empty.

Therefore `countryName , countryCode ,  isoCode`  are all `null`, hence the NPE in the `postExecute()` of `CountryData`.

See if this string `newsReaderUrls.BASE_URL + newsReaderUrls.COUNTRY_URL`, when put in a browser returns a valid URL and a proper xml

Answer (score 0):

Could the URL be in an internal network by any chance that you don't have access from the device? Also, did you take the result and put it in an XML parser/validator?

Comment: --Thanks for reply..
But same code is working on android 2.3 & above & same code is not working on Android 2.2 & below.

Some one told me there are few bugs in Android 2.2 may be that's the reason but I am not sure.